# Remove Name Based jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use the jQuery validation plugin to validate forms, but I need to completely remove the ability for it to use the name attribute.  Part of my form is created dynamically based on a counter being incremented and I simply want to use classes only.

Is there a way to do this?

I've implemented the addClassRules method and added all my classes for each field, but if I remove the class from the field it still validates based on the name field.

This is really starting to get frustrating.

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
    username: { 
        required: true, 
        minlength: 2, 
        remote: "whatever.php" 
    }
});
```

etc.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="username">
        <?php echo $entry_username; ?>
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-large" 
               name="username" id="username" 
               value="<?php echo $username; ?>" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see this element does NOT have a class of username, but the validation falls back to use the name attribute if the class isn't present.

I want to use classes ONLY for validation.

Thanks.

Comment: put pieces of your code here.

Comment: Its even more frustrating for others to see questions they cant understand. So yes, please add some code pieces/a fiddle perhaps to get your question across.

Comment: Not sure why this question requires code ... I'm not asking for code to be debugged, I'm asking how to turn off the name attribute fallback, but ... code added anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the built-in `rules()` method to add rules and assign them by `class`.  [See documentation.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules)

Note:  You **must** call this method *after* you call `.validate()`.

I have a very large form where the user can dynamically add fields.  This is the exact method I use to make sure my newly created fields are also part of the validation.

(If you remove the `class` from the `input`, it will **not** (can not) validate on the `name` attribute because the `name` attribute is not used anywhere within the `.validate()` options or rules.)

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" class="myclass" name="whatever" />
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#form").validate({
    // my options
});

// the following method must come AFTER .validate()
$('#form').find('.myclass').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        messages: {
            required: "Required input",
            minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters are necessary")
        }
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kSFKE/)

Comment: bazinga.. this saved me like 2 days of headaches. Freaking asp.net and their changing of the name property. I came up with a solution to change the name properties using jquery but then i broke viewstate. This works perfect. I saw something like this before but didn't realize you could attach messages too.

Answer (score -1):

1. Simply download the source, e.g., http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.js, and then,
2. Do a search replace for the word `name` and replace it with another attribute, like `validate_on`
3. Use that new source in place of the old one.

Answer (score -1):

What if you use a specific class name just for validation? Something that is different from `name`?

For example: `validatable-username` (Doesn't have to be that long, but you get my idea)

Then it can't fallback to the name.